# Interactive command line from within MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've been writing and running queries from within MySQL workbench's SQL Query Panel. However, sometimes I need to run a one-off command (e.g. adding indices) that I don't want to save.

Right now, I write it in the query file, run, then delete from the file. Can I open a command line within MySQL workbench to run these one-off commands? If not, is it okay if I open another database connection from my OS terminal alongside my MySQL workbench connection?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-query-panel.html

Comment: The query panel (which you link to) is what I meant by "script file". I have to manually delete the query from the query panel after running it.

Comment: The question is strange. MySQL's base use **is** the command line (which is by nature "interactive"). MySQL Workbench adds to that. You can have as many sql editors as you want each with own stuff to run (even temporary). Edit objects using the object editors (right click on the object, e.g. table, to edit it).

Comment: I know that I can run mysql from OS terminal. The question is specifically about whether there is a built-in terminal within Mysql workbench

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: New Query]

Click the first item in the toolbar. The "SQL" with the "+" sign. You'll get a new query tab. If you don't want to save the new query, just don't click the Save icon. Close the tab when you're done.

Comment: So basically there is no interactive command line. I just want to confirm that, since coming from the R statistical language, we can run command both interactive from script and from command line.

Comment: Right. MySQL Workbench improves on the command-line interface. It's basically the same thing, only here the query results come back in a scrollable, exportable list, rather than as text on the screen. Anything you can do at the "command line", you can do here.